# Does the TLS cert would require an common SAN

Tags: security, ssl, haproxy

Based on the below reference link in configuring Haproxy with TLS:

Do i need to have the certificates generated with common SAN(Subject ALternate name) on all the target nodes (or)

Having the individual certs without any common SAN would work ?

https://serversforhackers.com/c/using-ssl-certificates-with-haproxy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/172626/chrome-requires-san-names-in-certificate-when-will-other-browsers-ie-follow : some browsers (Chrome) require names to be in the SAN part as they disregard now completely the CN field

So even for a one domain certificate you need the domain both in the CN (as this is not optional) and in the SAN part.

It is also in the [CAB Forum requirements](https://cabforum.org/wp-content/uploads/CA-Browser-Forum-BR-1.6.0.pdf), section 7.1.4.2.1 :

> Certificate Field: extensions:subjectAltName
>
> Required/Optional: Required
>
> Contents: This extension MUST contain at least one entry.
> Each entry MUST be either a dNSName containing the Fully-Qualified
> Domain Name or an iPAddress containing the IP address of a server.
> The CA MUST confirm that the Applicant controls the Fully-Qualified
> Domain Name or IP address or has been granted the right to use it by
> the Domain Name Registrant or IP address assignee, as appropriate.
> Wildcard FQDNs are permitted.

Note that some other browsers, like Firefox, fallback to the CN instead, see https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1245280 and see beginning of patch at https://hg.mozilla.org/mozilla-central/rev/dc40f46fae48 for the `security.pki.name_matching_mode` configuration option.

Comment: i'm sorry if the question was not clear , with SAN what i meant is to have an common aliasname across all the nodes that's going to be placed in loadbalancer config

Comment: of-course SAN in the new thing, which by default have the CN name assigned to it , in case of not having multiple aliases

Comment: SAN is not new technology. See https://www.digicert.com/subject-alternative-name.htm : The Subject Alternative Name extension was a part of the X509 certificate standard before 1999, but it wasn't until the launch of Microsoft Exchange Server 2007 that it was commonly used; this change makes good use of Subject Alternative Names by simplifying server configurations. Now Subject Alternative Names are widely used for environments or platforms that need to secure multiple sites (names) across different domains/subdomains.

Comment: Thank you for your clarifications